# pasting consecutive data in a row into another row but in every other column

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuzqX.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZFGe.png)I have a row of data that needs to be pasted into another row but with the data being pasted into every other column for purposes of creating a side by side stacked bar chart for comparing actual versus budgeted month over month numbers.

Please see pictures below of current data and desired outcome.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: Sub PasteUsingOffset()

    Dim FirstRange As Range
    Dim SecondRange As Range
    
    Set FirstRange = Range("B2:M2")
    Set SecondRange = FirstRange.Offset(6, 2)
    
   'Copy from the first range. Paste in the second.
    FirstRange.Copy SecondRange

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following procedure should do the trick if you adjust the worksheet name as well as the data and the target range to fit your data:

```
Sub CopyDataOffset()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim ws As Worksheet, cell, dataRng, targetRng As Range, nOff As Long
    
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set dataRng = ws.Range("A1:E1")
Set targetRng = ws.Range("A2")
    
    For Each cell In dataRng.Cells
        targetRng.Offset(0, nOff).Value = cell.Value
        nOff = nOff + 2
    Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Karl, new here and still learning the how stack overflow operates.  It did work. That said, one other question, I want to do the exact same function to pull the budget and fill to the adjacent column that the actuals were placed. So it would look like this. Do I just need to change the name of the variable "dataRng" and "targetRng" ? Any guidance would be great. Just to clarify, the second part involves bringing the highlighted cells down - see picture above that I added.

Comment: @AaronDunn Great! Well, you could take 2 approaches. Either run the macro a second time with the adjusted ranges. In this case, set the dataRng according to your data and the target range to, e.g., "B2". Which will place the budget columns then in every other column starting with B2. Or simply put it in the same procedure with the new ranges respectively and use the for each to the new range accordingly (duplicate the procedure for the budget rows). In this case, you also need to initialize the new ranges as Dim Range and set the ranges according to your needs as well as duplicate the loop.

Comment: I got it! Thanks again for the assistance! Big help!

Comment: Hi Karl, One other question, if I wanted to pull data from a different sheet within a workbook, how would I modify the code to produce the same result?

Comment: @AaronDunn One way would be to simply set an additional sheet (similar to Sheet1) and then copy from the specific sheet accordingly. The procedure is in the end the same, just the additional specification of the sheet.

Comment: Hi Karl, The issue I am having is that when the data is pulled into the new sheet, it is only pasting the last cell (D273) into every cell. Sub GenesisGrossRollup()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim ws As Worksheet, cell, dataRng, targetRng As Range, nOff As Long
    
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Genesis")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GROSSversusNET")
Set dataRng = ws1.Range("D268:D273")
Set targetRng = ws2.Range("T7:Y7")
    
    For Each cell In dataRng.Cells
        targetRng.Offset(nOff, 0).Value = cell.Value
    Next cell

End Sub

Comment: Do you know what I am doing wrong?